# Can I monitor Windows 10 update sharing feature?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, updates

Is it possible to monitor updates shared by the Windows 10 update sharing feature?

I'm interested in the number of shared updates and especially their size (corresponding to saved bandwith). Scrubbing through some log files or the system events is fine, so is changing the Windows configuration. If necessary, I would also go with third party software (like applications monitoring a given system service).

If it is possible to observe this traffic from *outside* Windows (for example, because the updates always get transmitted on some distinct, dedicated port), I could also monitor this traffic indirectly.

Comment: I doubt anyone has done this and Microsoft is not going to tell, you will just have to start sniffing packets using Wireshark and see if you can figure it out.

Comment: Using Wireshark over your home network is probably your only option, but I wouldn't be surprised if they were encrypted in some way.

Comment: This is all I can find from Microsoft...http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-update-delivery-optimization-faq